# List reports with inline SQL in SQL Server Reporting Services?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, inline

I have a couple of inline SQL in many of our reports on the report manager.
Now I need to do some code change for all of them, is there a way to list all those reports based on the inline SQL and not any SP?

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 1):

You can use the reporting services API to get the report from the web service and do a search for the appropriate tags in the XML.  The MSDN documentation for the report definition XML schema and diagrams can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155062.aspx) and a diagram of the data source related parts [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677408.aspx)  The API documentation can be found [here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155076.aspx)

You can write .Net programs that upload and download reports from the Reporting Services API, using [ReportingService.GetReportDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258101(SQL.80).aspx) and [SetReportDefinition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258544(SQL.80).aspx).  You can upload or download the report definition into a buffer, which can be read or written to disk.  Somewhere I have an Ironpython prototype that does this, which I'll post if I find it.

To use this, you need to query the WSDL and generate a stub.  The tool to do this is called [WSDL.EXE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.71).aspx).  If I can find it I'll post it here, but you could just as easily use C#.

There is also a tool called [rs.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa256617(SQL.80).aspx) that comes with [BIDS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms170338.aspx) which takes a VB.net program and tops and tails it with includes for the Reporting Services API.  You can use this to execute a VB.Net script from the command line - essentially it tops and tails the program, compiles it behind the scenes and runs it against a report server.

Answer (score 1):

You can either do what NXC suggested or if this is a one time activity, you can simply open the RDL file for the report in a text editor and search for common SQL strings like "select", "delete" etc in order to find the reports which have inline SQL